# Updates and computes a column TOP 1 using trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a post here and I think this is the continuation on that but with a little twist. I posted before about parsing of data and inserting it using triggers and stored procedures but Now, I'm posting for triggers. When the parsed data inserted into a table I have this trigger that will update the inserted data. It will compute a column.

Here's the computation

```
Hex convert to dec * 1.852 = Meter convert to Kilometer
```

Here's the code for my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[computeKMRUN2]
ON [dbo].[tblKMRUN2]
AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
    declare @hex nvarchar(10)
    declare @RM nvarchar(10)
    declare @res varchar(10)
    declare @kmres varchar(10)

    select @hex = (SELECT TOP 1 KmRun from tblKMRUN2)
    SET @RM = (SELECT ('select convert (int,0x'+   @hex + ')' ))
    SET @res = (SELECT (@RM *  1.852) AS meterres)
    SET @kmres = (SELECT (@res /  1000.0) AS kmres)

    UPDATE tblKMRUN2 
    SET KmRun = @kmres 
    WHERE KmRun = @hex;
END
```

Whenever I tried using this, an error occurs:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure computeKMRUN2, Line 11
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

This is the data for this one to test with

```
0DF90F
```

Comment: In the above trigger the RM variable has the value string 'select convert (int,0x0DF90F)'. Then how can you multiply the 1.852 value with the RM value(select convert (int,0x0DF90F))?

Comment: Triggers have `inserted` (and `deleted`) pseudo tables that contain the rows affected by the statement that they're firing for. If you have a trigger that doesn't reference these tables, it's almost certainly broken. You current trigger is *horribly* broken as soon as more than one row exists in `tblKMRUN2`. For starters, `(SELECT TOP 1 KmRun from tblKMRUN2)` is effectively saying "give me one random `KmRun` value from any row in this table, I don't even care if it's a row that was just created"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `CAST` the `NVARCHAR` value to `NUMERIC` while performing `AIRTHMETIC` calculation.

```
SET @res = (SELECT ( CAST(@RM AS NUMERIC(32,3)) *  1.852) AS meterres)
SET @kmres = (SELECT (CAST(@res AS NUMERIC(32,3)) /  1000.0) AS kmres)
```

**Update: Modified Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[computeKMRUN2]
 ON [dbo].[tblKMRUN2]
 AFTER INSERT
 AS BEGIN
 declare @hex nvarchar(10)
 declare @RM nvarchar(MAX)
 declare @res varchar(10)
 declare @kmres varchar(10)
 declare @nRMVal AS INT
    select @hex=(SELECT TOP 1 KmRun from tblKMRUN2)

    SET @RM = 'select @nRMVal = convert (int,0x'+  @hex + ')' 

    EXEC sp_executesql @RM , N'@nRMVal INTEGER OUTPUT', @nRMVal OUTPUT


    SET @res = (SELECT (@nRMVal *  1.852) AS meterres)
    SET @kmres = (SELECT (@res /  1000.0) AS kmres)

    UPDATE  tblKMRUN2 set KmRun = @kmres where KmRun = @hex;
END
```

Comment: Is there anyway in the SQL world can i store an execute query inside a variable.Like this one `SET @RM = execute ('select convert (int,0x'+   @hex + ')' )`

Comment: Got this error mmessage`Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure computeKMRUN2, Line 13
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'select @nRMVal = convert (int,0x000000)' to data type int.`

Comment: @Dodgeball: Use the updated result and reply the status.

Comment: Here's the reply`Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 14
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

(0 row(s) affected)
`

Comment: Here's another reply this time it did affected 1 row  `Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 14
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

(1 row(s) affected)`

Comment: @Dodgeball:Change the datatype of variable nRMVal AS REAL.